# key up function on 3 different fields in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

In my form I have 3 text fields and under the text fields i display the number of characters left. To do that i am using key up function . However it only works on one field. How do i make this key up function work for each text field?

my form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<table class="table">
<tr style="background:#3C8DBC;">
<th>Day 1</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
     <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="day1content" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Content:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
      <textarea name="day1content" id="day1content" width="300px" cols="60" rows="8" id="content"></textarea>
        Characters left:  (<b id="smsLength"></b>) 
         <b id="smsCount"></b> /2 SMS <br />
       </div>
     </div>
   </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
     <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="content2" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Content:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
      <textarea name="day2content" id="day2content" width="300px" cols="60" rows="8" id="content"></textarea>
        Characters left:  (<b id="smsLength2"></b>) 
         <b id="smsCount2"></b> /2 SMS <br />
       </div>
     </div>
   </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
     <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="day3content" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Content:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
      <textarea name="day3content" id="day3content" width="300px" cols="60" rows="8" id="content"></textarea>
        Characters left:  (<b id="smsLength3"></b>) 
         <b id="smsCount3"></b> /2 SMS <br />
       </div>
     </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    (function($){
      $.fn.smsArea = function(options){

        var
        e = this,
        cutStrLength = 0,

        s = $.extend({

            cut: true,
            maxSmsNum: 2,
            interval: 400,

            counters: {
                message: $('#smsCount'),
                character: $('#smsLength')
            },

            lengths: {
                ascii: [160, 306, 459],
                unicode: [70, 134, 201]
            }
      }, options);


        $('#day1content').keyup(function(){

            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
            this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){

                var
                smsType,
                smsLength = 0,
                smsCount = -1,
                charsLeft = 0,
                text = $('#day1content').val(),
                isUnicode = false;

                for(var charPos = 0; charPos < text.length; charPos++){
                    switch(text[charPos]){
                        case "\n": 
                        case "[":
                        case "]":
                        case "\\":
                        case "^":
                        case "{":
                        case "}":
                        case "|":
                        case "€":
                            smsLength += 2;
                        break;

                        default:
                            smsLength += 1;
                    }

                    //!isUnicode && text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€" && (isUnicode = true)
                    if(text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€")
                    isUnicode = true;
                }

                if(isUnicode)   smsType = s.lengths.unicode;
                else                smsType = s.lengths.ascii;

                for(var sCount = 0; sCount < s.maxSmsNum; sCount++){

                    cutStrLength = smsType[sCount];
                    if(smsLength <= smsType[sCount]){

                        smsCount = sCount + 1;
                        charsLeft = smsType[sCount] - smsLength;
                        break
                    }
                }

                if(s.cut) $('#day1content').val(text.substring(0, cutStrLength));
                smsCount == -1 && (smsCount = s.maxSmsNum, charsLeft = 0);

                s.counters.message.html(smsCount);
                s.counters.character.html(charsLeft);

            }, s.interval)
        }).keyup()
    }}(jQuery));


    //Start
    $(function(){
        $('#day1content').smsArea({maxSmsNum:2});
    });
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    (function($){
      $.fn.smsArea = function(options){

        var
        e = this,
        cutStrLength = 0,

        s = $.extend({

            cut: true,
            maxSmsNum: 2,
            interval: 400,

            counters: {
                message: $('#smsCount2'),
                character: $('#smsLength2')
            },

            lengths: {
                ascii: [160, 306, 459],
                unicode: [70, 134, 201]
            }
      }, options);


        $('#day2content').keyup(function(){

            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
            this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){

                var
                smsType,
                smsLength = 0,
                smsCount2 = -1,
                charsLeft2 = 0,
                text = $('#day2content').val(),
                isUnicode = false;

                for(var charPos = 0; charPos < text.length; charPos++){
                    switch(text[charPos]){
                        case "\n": 
                        case "[":
                        case "]":
                        case "\\":
                        case "^":
                        case "{":
                        case "}":
                        case "|":
                        case "€":
                            smsLength += 2;
                        break;

                        default:
                            smsLength += 1;
                    }

                    //!isUnicode && text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€" && (isUnicode = true)
                    if(text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€")
                    isUnicode = true;
                }

                if(isUnicode)   smsType = s.lengths.unicode;
                else                smsType = s.lengths.ascii;

                for(var sCount = 0; sCount < s.maxSmsNum; sCount++){

                    cutStrLength = smsType[sCount];
                    if(smsLength <= smsType[sCount]){

                        smsCount2 = sCount + 1;
                        charsLeft2 = smsType[sCount] - smsLength;
                        break
                    }
                }

                if(s.cut) $('#day2content').val(text.substring(0, cutStrLength));
                smsCount2 == -1 && (smsCount2 = s.maxSmsNum, charsLeft2 = 0);

                s.counters.message.html(smsCount2);
                s.counters.character.html(charsLeft2);

            }, s.interval)
        }).keyup()
    }}(jQuery));


    //Start
    $(function(){
        $('#day2content').smsArea({maxSmsNum:2});
    });
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function($){
      $.fn.smsArea = function(options){

        var
        e = this,
        cutStrLength = 0,

        s = $.extend({

            cut: true,
            maxSmsNum: 2,
            interval: 400,

            counters: {
                message: $('#smsCount3'),
                character: $('#smsLength3')
            },

            lengths: {
                ascii: [160, 306, 459],
                unicode: [70, 134, 201]
            }
      }, options);


        $('#day3content').keyup(function(){

            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
            this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){

                var
                smsType,
                smsLength = 0,
                smsCount2 = -1,
                charsLeft2 = 0,
                text = $('#day3content').val(),
                isUnicode = false;

                for(var charPos = 0; charPos < text.length; charPos++){
                    switch(text[charPos]){
                        case "\n": 
                        case "[":
                        case "]":
                        case "\\":
                        case "^":
                        case "{":
                        case "}":
                        case "|":
                        case "€":
                            smsLength += 2;
                        break;

                        default:
                            smsLength += 1;
                    }

                    //!isUnicode && text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€" && (isUnicode = true)
                    if(text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€")
                    isUnicode = true;
                }

                if(isUnicode)   smsType = s.lengths.unicode;
                else                smsType = s.lengths.ascii;

                for(var sCount = 0; sCount < s.maxSmsNum; sCount++){

                    cutStrLength = smsType[sCount];
                    if(smsLength <= smsType[sCount]){

                        smsCount3 = sCount + 1;
                        charsLeft3 = smsType[sCount] - smsLength;
                        break
                    }
                }

                if(s.cut) $('#day3content').val(text.substring(0, cutStrLength));
                smsCount3 == -1 && (smsCount3 = s.maxSmsNum, charsLeft3 = 0);

                s.counters.message.html(smsCount3);
                s.counters.character.html(charsLeft3);

            }, s.interval)
        }).keyup()
    }}(jQuery));


    //Start
    $(function(){
        $('#day3content').smsArea({maxSmsNum:2});
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would write it.  Your code will take a bit of adaption, but it shouldn't be too hard.  If you're wondering, I reference maxlength for the sake of adaptability and also having a built-in way of stopping the user from going over the limit.

```js
$(".container input").on('keydown', function () {
 $(this)
  .parents(".container")
  .find(".smsCount")
  .html($(this).attr("maxlength") - $(this).val().length);
});

$(".container input").trigger('keydown');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <input type="text" maxlength="160" /> 
 <div class="smsCount"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <input type="text" maxlength="160" /> 
 <div class="smsCount"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <input type="text" maxlength="160" /> 
 <div class="smsCount"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx nfn neil for the reply, really appreciate you time. You are right this is how i did it. but my input will allow chinese input too. therefore i had to do it this way :( .

Comment: I was primarily referring to one issue.  You are using id's which unnecessarily make relative parameters harder.

Comment: should i use class instead u mean?

Comment: Yes.  Use a class for sms characters remaining.

Comment: but right now i have 3 scripts for each field, i will still have to use 3 different class names right?

Comment: No, you'd have one class name.

Comment: what about the script ? keep three of them for each field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137983/discussion-between-mikethetechy-and-nfn-neil).